# WPF groupbox header crops font descender

Tags: c#, wpf

The WPF GroupBox Header text font descender is always cropped. i.e. the g and p letters are cropped at the bottom. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <GroupBox Header="Page Setup" Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            ...
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
```

The result looks like this:
[Page Setup example header text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhkY5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you will only see this in **Design** mode like here:

[image]

Once you run it it will be fine.

[image]

Typically you can set `padding` attribute to move whatever element you are hosting away from the `GroupBox` border and header. It does not seems to do much difference in design mode unfortunately.